# VSCode - REST Client extension - How to run all tests?

Tags: rest, visual-studio-code

In [REST Client extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=humao.rest-client) for VS Code,

is there any way to run all REST tests?

Comment: This is not supported  at the moment. There is a bunch of open issues to support this feature in project github, here is a one of those: https://github.com/Huachao/vscode-restclient/issues/1092